# Is there a way to check the arity of Rcpp::Function?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rcpp11

I need to check the arity of a function in an Rcpp block at run time. What I would like to do is something akin to the following:

```
double loglikelihood(Rcpp::List data, Rcpp::List params, SEXP i, Rcpp::RObject custom_function) {
    Rcpp::Function f = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::Function>(custom_function);
    double res = 0.0;
    if (arity(f) == 3) {
        res = Rcpp::as<double>(f(data, param, i));
    } else if (arity(f) == 2) {
        res = Rcpp::as<double>(f(data, param));
    }
    return res;
}
```

However, the limited documentation I've seen for Rcpp does not seem to contain a function for checking the arity of an Rcpp::Function. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If `custom_function` is an R function, you can check arity on the R side: `length(formals(custom_function))`. You could try to reproduce the `formals` function in C, but I wouldn't bother.

Comment: `length(formals(custom_function))` is exactly what I need, but I need it on the C++ side, rather than the R side. I've solved this for now by passing a two element list with the function and the arity, rather than passing just the function, but that's a bit hacky.

Comment: since you are already calling R code from your C++ function, why not call the formals function using `Rcpp::Function` there too? That's what I meant when I said I wouldn't bother writing the function in C++.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood. That's actually a really neat idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this using a workaround that is a little bit clunky but after giving it some serious thought, this is the least clunky of three methods I tried implementing.

The method I ended up going with is checking the arity of the function on the R side using `methods::formalArgs`, wrapping the (function, arity) pair in a list and passing that to the Rcpp function like so:

```
double loglikelihood(Rcpp::List data, Rcpp::List params, 
                     SEXP i, Rcpp::RObject custom_function) {
    Rcpp::List l = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::List>(custom_function);
    Rcpp::Function f = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::Function>(l[0]);
    int arity = l[1];

    double res = 0.0;
    if (arity == 3) {
        res = Rcpp::as<double>(f(data, param, i));
    } else if (arity == 2) {
        res = Rcpp::as<double>(f(data, param));
    }
    return res;
}
```

As I mentioned, this is a bit clunky and it changes the signature of the funciton, which is not ideal. Another way of doing this would be to use the forgiveness-rather-than-permission approach and doing the control flow in a try-catch block, like so:

```
double loglikelihood(Rcpp::List data, Rcpp::List params, 
                     SEXP i, Rcpp::RObject custom_function) {

    Rcpp::Function f = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::Function>(custom_function);

    double res = 0.0;
    try {
        res = Rcpp::as<double>(f(data, param, i));
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        res = Rcpp::as<double>(f(data, param));
    }
    return res;
}
```

This approach is less clunky, but the problem with it is that it also catches other exceptions that might arise within `f` and silences them so they aren't passed to the user. It is possible that there are more fine-grained exceptions defined in Rcpp that would be able to catch the specific error of passing too many parameters, but if so I haven't found it.

Lastly, we could pass `methods::formalArgs` to `loglikelihood` and query the arity just before we need to use it, but I think this approach is the clunkiest of the three, because it requires us to pass `formalArgs` around a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The "limited documentation" (currently ten pdf vignettes alone) tells you, among other things, that all we have from R itself is `.Call()` returning `SEXP` and taking (an arbitrary number of) `SEXP` objects which can be a function.  So all this ... goes back to the *R API* which may, or may not, have such an accessor which may or may not be public and supposed to be used by anybody but R itself.

These days we register compiled functions with R (typically in a file `src/init.c` or alike) where this number of argument is *passed on* as an second argument (beyond the function call name) when making the registration.  Which suggests to me that it is not discoverable.